# Can I return new copy of only part of a state object instead of the entire state object

Tags: javascript, redux, redux-framework

I have the following initial state that consists of flat properties and one deep nested property `searchStatus`:

```
var searchStatus = Immutable.fromJS({
    requesting: {
        component: {tenants: false, platforms: false},
        tenant: false,
        hdf: false,
        cluster: false
    }
});

const initialState = {
    selectedItem: null,
    searchQuery: '',
    searchStatus: searchStatus
};
```

I have a reducer that works with this state:

```
function reducer(state = initialState, action) {
        switch (action.type) {
            case GET_TENANT_TEMPLATES_LISTING_REQUEST:
                var status = state.searchStatus.updateIn(['requesting', 'component', 'tenants'], function () {
                    return true;
                });
                return assign({}, state, {
                    searchStatus: status
                });
```

Is it OK to return new copy only for `searchStatus` part of the state and then merge it into the state or should I always return the entire state copy?

**UPDATE**:

```
case GET_TENANT_TEMPLATES_LISTING_REQUEST:
    var copy = assign({}, state);
    copy.searchStatus.requesting.component.tenants = true;
    return copy;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must copy the state object over every time (note that internal references can be kept, so it's not as inefficient as you may think), which is what you're doing with your `assign` (which I can only assume is a shorthand for `Object.assign()`)

Your call to assign will copy over all of the properties from state, and then from `{ searchStatus: status }`, to an empty object, effectively copying over your entire state, and then applying changes.

You must not mutate the state passed into the function, and you must also return a complete state object from the function.

Comment: thanks, if internal references remain the same, is the approach I specified in my question's update possible?

Comment: No. Because that will mutate the original state object as well, as the references remain the same. Stick with `Object.assign()`

Comment: for some reason I can't see the difference between the two. Can you please provide a bit elaborate explanation?

Comment: `Object.assign()` will replace the entire reference with a different reference, your **UPDATE:** approach will change something within the reference, which is shared with the original object, thus changing the original object.

Comment: Thanks, but my second approach also uses Object.assign, and the mutation is then made in a cloned state. Why is this wrong? In my first approach I also make new copy of searchStatus, is that whats missing in the 2 approach?

Comment: @Maximus The mutation doesn't happen on a cloned object, it happens in one of the references which are on the cloned object. But the object in that reference is not cloned, it's shared between the clone and the original. So modifying it will change both. See https://jsfiddle.net/pwwttfv6/

Comment: I think I now understand, thanks! One more question though, for detecting changes it's enough to change a reference to a state object, why is there a requirement to also change references to inner objects so that inner state of an object doesnt change? Does it have something to do with structural sharing mechanism?

Comment: Can you please take a look at my these two questions if you have time: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34516484/what-is-the-correct-way-to-implement-transactions-with-redux) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34516894/why-is-the-requirement-to-always-return-new-object-with-new-internal-references) - both pertaining to `redux`