# What is the correct way to implement transactions with redux

Tags: javascript, redux, redux-framework

I need to run two queries to a server and if successful perform some action. Without `redux` I'd do it like that using `Q` library:

```
$q.all([service.doAction1(),service.doAction2()]).then(function(){
    //perform some actions
})
```

My question is how the same should be done using redux? My best guess is that I have to implement middleware which will use the same approach listed above:

```
function(next) {
 return function(action) {
    $q.all([service[action.requests[0]](),service[action.requests[1]]()]).then(function(result){
        next(result);
    })
 }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think either:

redux-thunk; See the async example here: https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk#motivation

or

redux-saga
  https://github.com/yelouafi/redux-saga

Would help solve your issue.