# Why is the requirement to always return new object with new internal references

Tags: javascript, redux, redux-framework

Redux requires that one always returns new state from reducers. For example, I have the following state:

```
let initialState = {
   prop: 3,
   internalReferenceProp: {a:3}
}
```

And the reducer that modifies `internalReferenceProp`. This reducer can be implemented to change only `state` object reference or both `state` and `internalProperty`:

```
function(state=initialState, action) {
  // changing only state reference
  let newState = Object.assign({}, state);
  newState.internalReferenceProp.a = 7;
  return newState;

  // changing both state and internalReferenceProp reference
  return Object.assign({}, state, {internalReferenceProp: {a:7}})
}
```

As I've been told first approach is not correct, so my question is what's the reasoning behind requirement to also change internal references? I understand that I should change `state` reference because it allows for an easy comparison to detect whether `state` changed, but why change internal references?

Comment: What's the `let newState` part used for?

Comment: @Louy, sorry, updated the code

Answer (score 2):

The first one is clearly not correct because `Object.assign` does a shallow copy, not a deep one.

```
// changing only state reference
let newState = Object.assign({}, state);

newState === state // false
newState.internalReferenceProp === state.internalReferenceProp // true

state.internalReferenceProp.a // 3
newState.internalReferenceProp.a = 7 // 7
state.internalReferenceProp.a // 7
```

You can see that this way, if we change something in `newState` it gets changed in `state` as well. This will make the change undetectable if a component is only interested in `internalReferenceProp`. This is also called a "side-effect" and is a bad practice.

In short, if your input (`state` in this case) changes in any way, it's called a side-effect and is wrong in redux.

Here's an example of why this is bad:

```
let data = getData(); // from redux

return (
  <ChildComponent someProp={data.internalReferenceProp} />
);
```

If we use the version with side-effects, `ChildComponent` will never re-render because its props didn't change. `oldData.internalReferenceProp === newData.internalReferenceProp`.

Comment: thanks, but that doesn't answer my question... _it's called a side-effect and is wrong in redux_ - my question is exactly why this is wrong

Comment: Added an example. Hope this helps.